# Deduce lowest type in hierarchy for template argument

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I'm trying to mess around with templates but I'm fairly new. When calling this function:

```
template <typename A, typename B, template<typename> typename Traversable, 
typename Fn>
auto map(const Traversable<A>& vec, Fn&& fn)
{
    Traversable<B> res{};
    for (A e : vec)
        res.push_back(fn(e));
    return res;
}
```

like this:

```
vector<int> numbers { 1,2,3,4,5 };
auto numbers_times_two = map(numbers, [](auto a) { return a * 2; });
```

I get an ambiguity error:

```
Inferred conflicting substitutions for template parameter Traversable (std::vector and std::_Vector_alloc)
```

As I see it, the compiler does not know whether to deduce `vector` or it's superclass for the `Traversable` parameter.

What's the best way to make the call to `map` compile *without* explicitly specifying the template parameters? A solution that works for other forward iterables such as `forward_list` and `array` would be appreciated.

Is there a generic solution to deduce the most specific class instead of a superclass in cases like this?

**Edit:** This happens only with the VS2017 compiler, but works with g++.

So after using [Jarod42s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51663627/7164767) I made my own container class just to see if the error still happens:

```
template <typename T>
class NewVec : public vector<T>
{
public:
    NewVec(initializer_list<T> il): vector<T>(il) {}
};

int main()
{
    NewVec<int> nv{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    auto doubled = map(nv, [](auto a) { return a * 2; });
}
```

And now the call compiles without issues. However `vector` and `forward_list` still yield the above error.

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
template <template <typename, typename...> class Container, typename T, typename F>
auto map(const Container<T>& vec, F&& f)
{
    using RetType = std::decay_t<decltype(f(*vec.begin()))>;
    Container<RetType> res{};
    for (auto&& e : vec)
        res.push_back(f(e));
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/925c06794f1119c8)

So all types are deducible.

Ideally, I would even remove `T` and use a `rebind::other` as allocators provide, but containers don't provide it.

Comment: Could you please explain your line of reasoning and how `decayt` (and for other readers `decltype`) work?

Comment: `decltype` allow to find the type of the expression basically `f(e)`. `std::decay_t` is to handle case when `f` return reference. `std::vector<T&>` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. But sadly, while your solution is certainly more generic, it still doesn't compile due to the ambiguity error explained above.

Comment: I have  just provided link [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/925c06794f1119c8), and it works. Can you provide more info about your error?

Comment: I just successfully compiled the code with `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp`
appently the error lies within the vs2017 compiler, or in the implementations. Apparently microsoft uses the superclass `_Vector_alloc` but GCC doesn't.